# purge sitecore analytics geoip records inside request pipeline

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-analytics

Our analytics database has alot of empty data stored in cachedValue.  This data seems to get returned forever.  I want to basically check that the required data is present in the cache, and if not, then do a new lookup.

I also want to allow testers to trigger this fresh lookup using a query string variable.

I've used reflector and noticed some Invalidate functions, but this appears to just clear cookies or remove the data from the in memory cache.  It looks like I want to set the cachedGeoIpHandle.GeoResolveState = Failed, not sure how to do this yet.

I also see exactly where I could make this happen in the GeoIpManager, but I can override, extend that class.

Thanks.